# Dando erro de Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)

Tags: c

Exercicio = Faça um procedimento que recebe, por parâmetro, 2 vetores de 10 elementos
inteiros e que calcule e retorne, também por parâmetro, o vetor intersecção dos dois
primeiros.

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 10

void interseccao(int vetor1[], int vetor2[], int vetor_interseccao[], int *x) {

int i, j;
int aux[50], x_aux = -1;


for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < TAM; j++) {
        if (vetor1[i] == vetor2[j]) {
            x_aux++;
            aux[x_aux] = vetor1[i];
        }
    }
}


if (x_aux != -1) {
    x_aux++;
    for (i = x_aux-1; i > - 1; i--) {
        for (j = 0; i < x_aux; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (aux[i] == aux[j]) {
                    aux[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x_aux; i++) {
        if (aux[i] != 0) {
            *x = *x +1;
            vetor_interseccao[*x] = aux[i];
        }
    }

}

}
int main () {

    int vetor1[TAM], vetor2[TAM], vetor_interseccao[TAM];
    int cont, x = -1;

    for (cont = 0; cont < TAM; cont++) {
        printf("Informe o valor do vetor1[%d]: ",cont+1);
        scanf("%d",&vetor1[cont]);
    }

    system("clear");

    for (cont = 0; cont < TAM; cont++) {
        printf("Informe o valor do vetor2[%d]: ",cont+1);
        scanf("%d",&vetor2[cont]);
    }

    system("clear");

    printf("---------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Valores do vetor1:\n\n");
    for (cont = 0; cont < TAM; cont++) {
        printf("vetor1[%d] = %d\n",cont+1,vetor1[cont]);
    }

    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Valores do vetor2:\n\n");
    for (cont = 0; cont < TAM; cont++) {
        printf("vetor2[%d] = %d\n",cont+1,vetor2[cont]);
    }

    interseccao(vetor1,vetor2,vetor_interseccao,&x);
    printf("\n---------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Valores do vetor_interseccao:\n\n");
    if (x != -1) {
        x++;
        for (cont = 0; cont < x; cont++) {
            printf("vetor_interseccao[%d] = %d\n",cont+1,vetor_interseccao[cont]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Não há valores de intersecção entre o vetor1 e o vetor2.\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cara, você está fazendo isso no linux? Isso geralmente é erro de permissão. Isso já aconteceu comigo ao tentar fazer certas coisas pelo terminal no pc do estágio.

Comment: Como assim cara ? Porque dá esse erro ?

Comment: Se estiver fazendo isso em um pc que não é o dono, pode ser que seja erro de permissão para executar o que quer. Entende? Estou me baseando em minha experiência com esse erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde,

"Debugando" o seu código percebi um erro bobo em um loop dentro do procedimento interseccao onde você trocou a variável de comparação de "J" para "I" por engano. Segue o trecho de código corrigido:

```
for (i = x_aux-1; i > - 1; i--) {
    for (j = 0; j < x_aux; j++) { //A condição estava i < x_aux
        if (i != j) {
            if (aux[i] == aux[j]) {
                aux[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero ter resolvido o seu problema.

Atenciosamente, Arthur Passos.